# Text area value not setting?

Tags: html, textarea

Im trying to set the textarea's value in normal HTML- no javascript. I am making sure I put the text within the tags and am not using a value attribute. However I cant get it to set the value oddly (Firefox Beta 10/9whateveritisnow)

```
echo "<textarea  name='input-".$day."-".$reqM."-".$reqY."'  class='calendar-textarea'>".$events[$time]."</textarea>";
```

this shows in the html as:

```
<textarea  name='input-1-1-2011'  class='calendar-textarea'>Hey calendar</textarea>
```

However it doesnt put the text in the text area? Any ideas as to why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aha! It appears firefox caches the text even when refreshed... So while I was editing, it had no value and it ended up just ignoring the text I put as the value. Rather annoying in all honesty.

Answer (score 0):

I bet  $events[$time] is not set or the textarea is invisible.

Comment: It is since its outputted in the html as "Hey calendar"

Comment: It works now... I answered my own question >.< Cant set it as answer though :/ ... It was because firefox was caching an empty result oddly